# append for loop output in single dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to append the for loop output in pandas dataframe as:

```
import pandas as pd
for i in range(1,5):
    p=i+4
    df = pd.DataFrame({'filename':i,'comments':p},index=[0])
    print (df)
```

It returns as multiple dataframe as:

```
   filename  comments
0         1         5
   filename  comments
0         2         6
   filename  comments
0         3         7
   filename  comments
0         4         8
```

Output expected as:

```
    filename comments
1   1         5
2   2         6
3   3         7
4   4         8
```

**I'm looking to build and fill a dataframe from a loop only**

Comment: (1) You can't append rows to a dataframe. (2) You create a new dataframe in each iteration. Solution: Append to Python lists in the loop and create the dataframe from them after loop.

Comment: @MichaelButscher I can't append the list outside the dataframe as ' I can have lists of unequal lengths'.  So, I want to append each row one by one into pandas dataframe inside loop only.

Answer (score 0):

You can append a list as a series to a dataframe like so

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['filename','comments'])
for i in range(1,5):
    df = df.append(pd.Series([i, i+4], index=df.columns), ignore_index=True)

print (df)
```

you must define the empty dataframe to begin with and then from within the loop append the list as a new row